# The source function in R

Tags: r

Suppose we have a program  `test.R`  that calls two other programs  `test1.R`  and  `test2.R` :

```
   source("test1.R")
   source("test2.R")
```

Does this mean that R runs  `test1.R`  first and then  `test2.R` ?

Answer (score 5):

In short, yes. From `?source`:

> Input is read and parsed from that file until the end of the file is
>   reached, then the parsed expressions are evaluated sequentially in the
>   chosen environment

To quote from Hadley Wickham in [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)

> When you load a script with source(), every line of code is executed
>   and the results are immediately made available.

So, when your script reaches `source("test1.R")` it will read, parse, and evaluate each expression in the file, then move on to `source("test2.R")` where it will do the same.

Comment: So if you want to perform some operations in <code> test2.R </code> before <code> test1.R </code>, you would have to switch the order of the source files?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, which makes it tricky to carry out operations in `source`ed files that aren't fully self contained. If you can, it would probably be simpler to have `test1.R` and `test2.R` define functions and objects and then carry out the actual operations in the main file or in another file `test3.R` which sources both test files.